# Cannot open windows store without fiddler

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-store, fiddler

I did a fresh install of windows 8 and connected to my microsoft account and  cannot connect to windows store. I tried [this](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-store-not-opening) but it did not work. But the fix in  [this link](http://www.superpctricks.com/2013/11/windows-8-store-is-not-connecting-to.html) somehow worked. Is there a permanent fix to this?

Comment: you're using Windows 8 and not 8.1, right?

Comment: yes windows 8, not 8.1

Comment: Are you using Pro or Core?

Comment: And which Language of Windows 8?

Comment: Windows 8 Pro ENG US

Comment: I need to revive this question, it happens in windows 10, and not just windows store, anything that is not Chrome or Firefox basically would not get connected without fiddler running, how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The only advice I could actually give is to upgrade to Windows 8.1 using an ISO, or the Windows Store.

---

### This is the MS recommended way

To Upgrade to using the Windows Store, you need to open the Windows Store, and look for the `Free Upgrade to Windows 8.1`

If you cannot find the upgrade, you will need to follow [this](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/why-can-t-find-update-store) guide to be able to recieve the upgrade.

---

### This is the alternate way

To Upgrade using the ISO Click on the link below:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

After that, you need to extract the ISO, and run setup.exe